# query to  find the total no: rows of the a table selected for past 30 days

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select past 30 days data and find the no: rows....i am getting a warning if i am calculating the no: rows. So is there any other alternative to find no: rows in the selected section.....my code is:

```
$thirty_reg=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY user.date DESC LIMIT 30");

$num_thirty=mysql_num_rows($thirty_reg);

echo $num_thirty;
```

A better suggestion to select the past 30 days data also is needed...

Comment: Are you wanting to count the number of rows that are present in the last 30 days of user.date?

Comment: LIMIT has two modes, with or witout offset, you should use that second

Comment: @Eric H Yup I want the no: rows but iget the warning if i calculate using: mysql_num_rows....any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your query to this to return rows for the past 30 days.

```
SELECT column FROM user WHERE user.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
```

However, I would recommend fetching the count of rows rather than a record set like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE user.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Comment: so does the second query directly return the no: rows?

Comment: The second query uses the aggregate function COUNT to return the number of items in the result set. This should work: $num_thirty = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT..."), 0);

Comment: $thirty_reg=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE user.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()");
$num_thirty=mysql_num_rows($thirty_reg);

Returned a warning
echo   $num_thirty;

Comment: $thirty_reg = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM user WHERE user.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()");

$row_thirty = mysql_fetch_assoc($thirty_reg);

$num_thirty = $row_thirty[count];

echo $num_thirty;

Comment: Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Users\

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Users\balu\Documents\My Web Sites\Untitled_1.php on line 38

 Notice: Use of undefined constant count - assumed 'count' in C:\Users\balu\Documents\My Web Sites\Untitled_1.php on line 39

@ warnings

Comment: I can't help you further. I don't have a PHP environment to work with. Code above is to the best of my recollection.

Comment: ok no problem everything is fine...it does return every time that rows mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT count(id) FROM user WHERE user.date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30);`

[Well someone beat me to it haha.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11210227/662565)